# Change style of html links in TextViews after executing Html.fromHtml

Tags: java, android, textview, html-parsing, text-styling

I'm developing an android application. I retrieve some data that looks like this:

```html
<a href="http://google.com/" title=''><b><font color="gold">My Link to Google!</font></b></a>
```

I'm applying it to a TextView like this:

```java
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(myHtmlString));
```

The issue I encounter here is that Html.fromHtml seems to apply a general styling

[image: Text example]

to any and all links, which is to color them blue and underline them. I'd rather not have it do this, is there any simple solution to make it not stylize links(and therefore, I assume, "font color=whatever" would apply instead)? The behavior does not change if the HTML link tag is on the inside of font/style tags.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `android:textColorLink` attribute. I'm afraid it's the only way to change link color.

If you're sure that you have only one link in the text then you can do the following:

```
Spanned text = Html.fromHtml(myHtmlString);
ForegroundColorSpan spans[] = text.getSpans(0, text.length(),
    ForegroundColorSpan.class);
if (spans.length > 0) {
    myTextView.setLinkTextColor(spans[0].getForegroundColor());
}
myTextView.setText(text);
```

Comment: I can modify that a little to suit my needs and use it. That'll do, thanks.